# SQL DB migration to Azure SQL using Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-migration, data-migration, azure-data-studio

I am not able to migrate on-premise SQL Server database to an Azure SQL database.

I am using Azure Data Studio while doing the migration. I am not able to "Select the tables" at the end, due to which I am not able to proceed next.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use [Azure Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) (DMA) instead. You can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595). Perform [an assessment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-assesssqlonprem?view=sql-server-ver16) first, you may need to fix some incompatibilities before migrating to Azure SQL. Once the incompatibilities have been fixed, try to migrate using DMA as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-migrateonpremsqltosqldb?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to migrate only the db without data, use .dacpac
if you want to migrate with data generate a bacpac and import it.

However the best and most reliable method for a migration from on premise to azure sql db would be to use Data migration assistant. It will allow you to do a pre assessment before the migration to list any compatibility issues. You can fix the issues and do a migration using this utility.

Answer (score 0):

"Make sure to migrate the database schema from source to target by using the SQL Server dacpac extension or the SQL Database Projects extension in Azure Data Studio before selecting the list of tables to migrate."

Did you do this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).